# how to show json values in imageview and textview?

Tags: android

this is my json file and code i want to print 3 json values in my imageview and text view
how do i set json valuesin my imageciew and textview?help me please in my code there is three attributes name  and url  how i set this to tree imageview and textview???

```
            {
 "worldpopulation": [
{
 "rank":1,
 "name": "BREAKFAST",
 "url": "http://niel986.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/fast-food.jpg"
 },
 {   
 "rank":2,
"name": "LUNCH ",
 "url": "http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/1107772406_1370520219.gif"
},
{  
"rank":3,
"name": "SUPPER",
 "url": "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JU_j7jj5TjU/TSBQKRukf1I/AAAAAAAAAs8/X1w5_z6pjwQ 
  /s1600/chicken-biryani.jpg"
}

]
 }
```

code :

```
    ImageView   img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);


       TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);


       ImageView    img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img2);


       TextView  txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);


       ImageView    img3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img3);


       TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);


    MenuSelect = Utils.MenuSelect;

     try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(),  
 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(MenuSelect);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
            JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");


        JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);

            String Name=e.getString("name");
            String url2=e.getString("url");
            txt1.setText(Name);
             Bitmap bitmap =     
      BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url2).getContent());
         img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //  IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: how to parse json value???help me please?????i ewan tto show "name"  and  "url" in imageview and textview

Comment: what problem u r getting while coding ?

Comment: JSONObject e = data.getJSONObject(i);  i cannot b resolve

Comment: i donot want to show on listview i want to show "name": "BREAKFAST",
 "url": "http://niel986.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/fast-food.jpg"

in my three imageview and textview

Comment: check my json parsoing code it is correct?????

Comment: where is i variable declared in ur class?

Comment: nothing i copy from here http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.com/p/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html

Comment: let me post u correct code, can u provide me json url?if possible on mail

Comment: jus tellme simply how to parse three  values from jsonsheet???

i want to print thre url in my three image view how i will do that help me???

Comment: json is in my localnetwork im asscess form local host  127.0.0.1////

Comment: i paste full json code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34363/discussion-between-stacks28-and-user2589245)

Answer (score 1):

```
    1) MainActivity

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


        LazyAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<AtmData> mAtmData;
        AtmData POIitem1;
         ListView list;
         Button btn;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
           btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttt);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent ii = new Intent(MainActivity.this,GoogleMap.class);
                    startActivity(ii);
                }
            });

            POIitem1 = new AtmData();

            Thread mUpdateThread1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

                    Connnn _con = new Connnn();

                    try {

                        mAtmData = _con.getAtmData(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=30.7046486,76.71787259999999&radius=1000&types=food&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAx8BKq8WTUzke6jnL1n4TqSvS5xHH5HFE");
                        Log.d("", "url" + mAtmData);
                    //  Log.d("", "url"
                        //      + "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=30.7046486,76.71787259999999&radius=1000&types=atm&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAx8BKq8WTUzke6jnL1n4TqSvS5xHH5HFE");
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // Log.d("sizeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",""+mLocationInfo.size());
                    MainActivity.this.handle.sendEmptyMessage(1);

                };
            };
          mUpdateThread1.start();
        }

        Handler handle = new Handler(){

            public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
                switch(msg.what)
                {
                case 1:
                    Log.d("murlllllllll","murllllllllllll"+ mAtmData);
                    for(int i=0;i<mAtmData.size();i++){
                        Log.d("murlllllllll","murllllllllllll"+ mAtmData.get(i).mlag);
                        Log.d("lnggggggggg","lnnnnnnnnnnnnggggg"+mAtmData.get(i).mlat);
                        Log.d("lconnnnnnn","iconnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"+mAtmData.get(i).micon);

                      }
                    adapter = new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, mAtmData);
                      list.setAdapter(adapter); 
                      Log.d("lsit","listttttttttt"+list);

            };

        };



        };


        }

2)LAzy Class..

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    ArrayList<AtmData> data;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    public LazyAdapter(MainActivity a, ArrayList<AtmData> data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

         mainActivity = a;
           this.data=data;
             inflater = (LayoutInflater)mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            imageLoader=new ImageLoader(mainActivity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    class AtmData2{
        public TextView title1,artist,adress;
        public ImageView _image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AtmData2 mAtmData2;
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            mAtmData2=new AtmData2();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

           mAtmData2.title1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title); 
        mAtmData2._image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1nnnnnnnnnnnn);

           mAtmData2.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
           mAtmData2.adress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration); // duration

           convertView.setTag(mAtmData2);
   } else {
       mAtmData2 = (AtmData2)convertView.getTag();
   }
        mAtmData2.title1.setText(data.get(position).mname);
        mAtmData2.artist.setText(data.get(position).mtypes);
        String _imgurl = this.data.get(position).micon.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        mAtmData2.adress.setText(data.get(position).mvicinity);


        mAtmData2._image.setTag(_imgurl);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(_imgurl,mainActivity, mAtmData2._image);


         return convertView;  
    }






    }


3) ImageLoader class;

public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public ImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    public void DisplayImage(String _imgurl, MainActivity mainActivity,
            Object _image) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Try this it May be help u..it is working for me.

Comment: i know how to decode url to imageview i just want tp o parse correctly imaeview and textview from json file???

Comment: in my josn file there is three rank   1,2,3 and three  name  and three url  i want to print 3  names in three textview and three url in three imageview how i will do that???

Comment: it is full code in which i implemt Text and imageview .so read carefully i try to understand the code

Comment: giveem ur email adress so i can sent u my json file

Comment: ListView doesn't matter dear u take any Layout or view it work .u use ur own view in the place of list view

Comment: balwinder.07.89@gmail.com

Comment: i alrady did somewhere else without adapter is working do u give me ur email adress so i canmail u my code so u easily understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34364/discussion-between-jelly-bean-and-user2589245)

Comment: w8 2 min im mailing  u

Comment: check my mail  please